# jquery load() - unable to load google maps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have trouble to load google maps while loading the contents of new page using `load()` in JQuery without reloading window.

Jquery ajax call is:

```
$("form").submit(function(){

        $(".cs-container").load("set-location.php .cs-container");
        return false;

    });
```

I am trying to load the contents of `.cs-container` from another `set-location.php` page in the current `div.cs-container` class element. it's loaded successfully **but the google maps does't load**. The `g-maps` container is placed in `.cs-container` in the `set-location.php` page and it's *script files* are contained in the head of that page.

`google maps` works very well but does't load in the ajax call.

when i try something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){

            $(".cs-container").load("set-location.php");
            return false;

        });
```

**it works very well but it load the complete page in the `.cs-container`. that I don't want.**

the google maps initializing script is as *(in the file `cs-loc.js`)*:

```
 /*check if geolocaiton supported*/
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}




function success(position) {


   var lat = position.coords.latitude; /*getting cordinates*/
   var long = position.coords.longitude;

   var input = document.getElementById("latLong");
   input.value = lat + ", " + long;

   var poos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long); /*set lat long for maps*/

    var mapProp = {
      center: poos,
      zoom:16,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp); /*init maps*/

    /*create marker*/
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:poos,
      title: 'Your Store Location',
      draggable: true
      });

    marker.setMap(map); /*set marker to map*/

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
        console.log(a);
        input.value = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
    });


}


success();
```

How it can be solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$.getScript()` in the `load()` callback

```
$(".cs-container").load("set-location.php .cs-container", function(){
    $.getScript('google.maps....').done(function(){           
           $.getScript('cs-loc.js');
   });    
});
```

Comment: what errors get thrown? What does or doesn't happen?